# What type of relationship is this and how should it be configured?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, .net-core, entity-framework-core, asp.net-identity

I am trying to create a discussion board using Identity where ApplicationUsers can create, save, hide, and comment on Posts. I was able to get Posts and Comments working without data annotations or overriding OnModelCreating as follows:

Post.cs:

```
public class Post
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public string Content { get; set; }
        [DataType(DataType.DateTime)]
        public DateTime CreationDate { get; set; }
        public ApplicationUser OriginalPoster { get; set; }
        public int Upvotes { get; set; }
        public int Downvotes { get; set; }
        public int VoteScore { get; set; }
        public ICollection<Comment> Comments { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment.cs:

```
public class Comment
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public string Content { get; set; }
        public ApplicationUser Commenter { get; set; }
        [DataType(DataType.DateTime)]
        public DateTime CreationDate { get; set; }
        public int Upvotes { get; set; }
        public int Downvotes { get; set; }
        public int VoteScore { get; set; }
    }
```

ApplicationDbContext.cs:

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext
    {
        public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> options)
            : base(options)
        {
        }

        public DbSet<Post> Posts { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Comment> Comments { get; set; }
    }
```

**But when I extend IdentityUser to add my own custom fields:**

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
    {
        public ICollection<Post> CreatedPosts { get; set; }
        public ICollection<Post> SavedPosts { get; set; }
        public ICollection<Post> HiddenPosts { get; set; }
    }
```

**Add-Migration returns with error:**

> "Unable to determine the relationship represented by navigation
> 'ApplicationUser.CreatedPosts' of type 'ICollection'. Either
> manually configure the relationship, or ignore this property using the
> '[NotMapped]' attribute or by using 'EntityTypeBuilder.Ignore' in
> 'OnModelCreating'."

Why is EF Core able to determine the relationship between a Post and its Comments but not an ApplicationUser and its created/saved/hidden Posts? I understand that I will have to specify the relationship either by using data annotations or overriding OnModelCreating but I am unsure of how to go about doing this. Any amount of help would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is because you have multiple collection properties referencing the same model, `Post`. This type of situation you need to specifically tell EF Core which foreign properties each of `CreatedPosts`, `HiddenPosts` and `SavedPosts` to reference from `Post`. Given you only have one `ApplicationUser` foreign property named `OriginalPoster`, that would be impossible because there are no other properties `HiddenPosts` and `SavedPosts` would reference. You would only be able to reference one by configuring it like this.

```
builder.Entity<ApplicationUser>().HasMany(s => s.CreatedPosts)
    .WithOne(f => f.OriginalPoster);
```

Now, which properties do the other two (`HiddenPosts` and `SavedPosts`) reference? I hope you see the problem here.

But assuming you have another type of poster defined in your `Post` model like this.

```
public ApplicationUser HiddenPoster {get;set;}
```

You make the collection it belongs to reference it as well.

```
builder.Entity<ApplicationUser>().HasMany(s => s.HiddenPosts)
    .WithOne(f => f.HiddenPoster);
```

But you don't, so this approach would not work because it's only one type of poster you have in your `Post`. I would suggest you redefined your model to have an enum in `Post` with values `Created`,`Hidden` and `Saved`.

```
public enum PostStatus
{
    Created,
    Hidden,
    Saved
}
```

Then define the status in the `Post` model like this.

```
public PostStatus Status {get;set;}
```

So that in your `ApplicationUser`, you do not have to define multiple collections, you only have `Posts`;

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{ 
    public ICollection<Post> Posts {get;set;}
}
```

and you can then filter which post is created, hidden or saved using the `Status` enum property from `Post`.